# Async Task Crashes Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am running multiple async tasks in one activity while the user can still switch to next or previous activities, the main issue i am having with async task is that when its running and user starts another activity it crashes the whole app resulting in null pointer exception.
i tried to cancel all running async task before calling startActivity but still no luck.

Here's my logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.threeamd.timeline.activity/com.threeamd.timeline.activity.ChaptersActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336):at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at com.threeamd.timeline.activity.ChaptersActivity.registerListners(ChaptersActivity.java:248)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at com.threeamd.timeline.activity.ChaptersActivity.onCreate(ChaptersActivity.java:168)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-19 10:29:27.268: E/AndroidRuntime(2336):     ... 11 more
```

Here's the code

```
private void initTweets() 
{
    lv_TweetsSection[0] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_GC_One);
    lv_TweetsSection[1] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_GC_Two);
    lv_TweetsSection[2] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_GC_Three);
    lv_TweetsSection[3] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_GC_Four);
    lv_TweetsSection[4] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_GC_Five);
    lv_TweetsSection[5] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_GC_Six);
    lv_TweetsSection[6] = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_GC_Seven);

    aSyncAdapters = new ArrayList<>(7);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        // new AsyncPullTweets(i+1 ,
        // this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        GcTweetFeed adapter = new GcTweetFeed(i + 1, this);
        lv_TweetsSection[i].setAdapter(adapter);
        aSyncAdapters.add(adapter);
    }

}
```

Here, I am running the task. My `AsyncTask` is in my adapter class

and this is where my AsyncTask runs

```
    public class GcTweetFeed extends BaseAdapter implements CustomAsyncInterface {

    public static boolean isActivityActive = false;
    private ArrayList<TweetModel> arrSectionTweets;
    private int secID;
//  private ListView refListView;
    public /*static*/ LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public View vi;
    private Activity activity;
    private CustomAsyncTask task;


    public GcTweetFeed(int secID , Activity a){
        this.secID = secID;


    }


    public void cancelRunningTask(){
        if((task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))||     (task.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.PENDING))){
            task.cancel(true);
        }

    }


    public GcTweetFeed(int secID , GcTweetFeed refAdapter ){
        this.secID = secID;
    //      this.refListView = refListView;
        arrSectionTweets = new ArrayList<>();

    //      arrSectionTweets.to

    }


    @Override
    public void customonPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public Object customDoInBackGround(String... params) {

        Log.d("CHKD", "EXE");

            //HERE I FETCH JSON

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void customOnProgressUpdated() {


    }

    @Override
    public void customOnPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //     this.refListView.setad
        if(isActivityActive){
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        Log.d("GCTFD", ""+secID);
    //      refListView.

    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (arrSectionTweets != null) {
            return arrSectionTweets.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


//      int xs = 100.25;
        vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflatetweets, null);
        TweetModel x = arrSectionTweets.get(position);

        ImageView pic = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_Tw_Pic);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(x.getProfile_picture() , R.drawable.thumbbackgroundns, pic );


         TextView tv_Name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.et_Tw_Name);
         TextView tv_TWName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tweets_TweeterName);
         TextView tv_Tweet = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.et_Tw_Tweet);

         tv_Name.setText(x.getUser_name());
         tv_TWName.setText(x.getTwitter_name());
         tv_Tweet.setText(x.getTweet());


         return vi;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Post your code and exception line number.

Comment: Which is line number 248 in ChaptersActivity.java, post the relevant code

Comment: Post your activity code.

Comment: at 248 i am just taking the reference positng my activity ccode

Comment: post the code, the reference is null, if its a context, you need to pass it in async task's constructor, can't help you without the code

Comment: i am using my interface for async task that i can call anywhere the issue is when activity is switched it crashes then

Comment: we need to see Your chaptersActivity, please post the code